Data Size difference Between Client-Proxy and Proxy-Server Connections with CONNECT Proxy
I have a small setup which I have a wss server running on port 4433. I also have a client trying to access the wss server via a CONNECT proxy. My understand of CONNECT proxy is that proxy will create a new TCP connection with wss server, and it will blindly relay the data it receives to this new TCP connection.
I was looking into the Wireshark capture and was expecting the size of the data transferred from client to proxy and then proxy to server to be the same and vice versa as well but that not the case. Am I missing something or is my understanding incorrect?
I am sorry for pasting the screenshot, but the formatting was all messed up when I tried to paste it as text.
My setup:
wss-client (37256) <-------> (3112) Proxy (47264) <--------> (4433) wss-server



TCP is a bytestream. The transferred data should be the same, but this does not mean that they are packetized in the same way for transport.

Ok, got it. So, its not possible to verify that by just looking at the "Length" fields in the above screenshot.
